# Facebook Like button for a specific id

Tags: php, html

From the homepage I will click on an image which has an id and then be directed to a page which shows more details about that id.

I want to have a facebook like button on the page that would contain information about that specific id but I don't know what to type in the data-href

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.test.com/php/test.php?id=" data-send="true" data-width="150" data-show-faces="false"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

specify that is it static or coming from database ?

for database, pass the php variable in the url:

```
echo "<div class='fb-like' data-href='http://www.test.com/php/test.php?id='".$id."data-send='true' data-width='150' data-show-faces='false'></div>";
```

Comment: It's coming from the database.

I have a query that uses $_GET['id']

But now when liking, it won't post to Facebook.